# How to post my data to API and read the response?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Actually, I'm doing an application in android. Now, I have to send these data of spinner, range date picker, and edit text data to API and should receive response. How I can do it?

I've tried and did not get any output.

I have tried this code.

```
   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    import com.Mobepay.Ewallet.Constants;
    import com.Mobepay.Ewallet.R;
    import com.Mobepay.Ewallet.activity.hotel.Result_page_travelumActivity;
    import com.Mobepay.Ewallet.app.Config;
    import com.Mobepay.Ewallet.app.MyApplication;
    import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;


    public class activity_book_hotel extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog1;
        private PrefManager prefnew;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private SharedPreferences pref;
        EditText city_id;
        private String first_date, last_date;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_hotel);

            city_id = findViewById(R.id.city_id);
            city_id.getText().toString();

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapteradult;
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterchild;
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterroom;

            String[] array_adult = {"1adult", "2adult", "3adult", "4adult"};
            String[] array_child = {"0child", "1child", "2child", "3child", "4child"};
            String[] array_rooms = {"1room", "2room", "3room", "4room"};

            Spinner adult_spinner = findViewById(R.id.adult_count);
            Spinner child_spinner = findViewById(R.id.child_count);
            Spinner room_spinner  = findViewById(R.id.room_val);

            adapteradult = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array_adult);
            adapteradult.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adult_spinner.setAdapter(adapteradult);

            adapterchild= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array_child);
            adapterchild.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            child_spinner.setAdapter(adapterchild);

            adapterroom= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array_rooms);
            adapterroom.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            room_spinner.setAdapter(adapterroom);

            String selectedadult  = adult_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String selectedchild  = child_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String selectedroom  = room_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            System.out.println(selectedadult+" "+selectedchild+" "+selectedroom);// check the output in logcat

            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_adults);
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_child);
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_rooms);


            Button btprcd = findViewById(R.id.btproced);
            btprcd.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                get_token_id();



            });

            final CalendarPickerView calendar_view = findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);

            Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
            nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
            Date today = new Date();

            calendar_view.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                    .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.RANGE);

            calendar_view.setOnDateSelectedListener(new CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSelected(Date date) {

                    String first_date = calendar_view.getSelectedDates().get(0).toString();
                    String last_date  = calendar_view.getSelectedDates().get(calendar_view.getSelectedDates().size()-1).toString();

                }

                @Override
                public void onDateUnselected(Date date) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Select Check in and Check out dates",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }



        private void get_token_id() {

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    Config.api_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = responseObj.getBoolean("error");
                        String message = responseObj.getString("message");

                        if (!error) {
                            responseObj.getJSONArray("token_details");

                            String city_id = responseObj.getString("city_id");
                            String check_in = responseObj.getString("check_in");
                            String check_out = responseObj.getString("check_out");
                            String room_val = responseObj.getString("room_val");
                            String adult_val = responseObj.getString("adult_val");
                            String child_val = responseObj.getString("child_val");
                            String adult_count = responseObj.getString("adult_count");
                            String child_count = responseObj.getString("child_count");
                            String child_age1 = responseObj.getString("child_age1");
                            String child_age2 = responseObj.getString("child_age2");
                            String ChildAge = responseObj.getString("child_age");

                            prefnew.set_hotel_city_id(city_id);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_check_in(check_in);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_check_out(check_out);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_room_val(room_val);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_adult_val(adult_val);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_child_val(child_val);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_adult_count(adult_count);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_child_count(child_count);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_child_age1(child_age1);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_child_age2(child_age2);
                            prefnew.set_hotel_ChildAge(ChildAge);

                            MyApplication.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(this);

                        } else {
                            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                pDialog.dismiss();

                            Toast.makeText(activity_book_hotel.this.getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if(message.equals("Sorry, We are not able to authenticate your device."))
                            {
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false);
                                editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,"");
                                editor.putString(Constants.NAME,"");
                                editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,"");
                                editor.apply();
                                editor.commit();


                                prefnew.setispincorrect(false);
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity_book_hotel.this, Result_page_travelumActivity.class);
                                startActivity(myIntent);
                            }
                        }
                        if (pDialog.isShowing())
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        if (pDialog.isShowing())
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(activity_book_hotel.this.getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Please Try again later."+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, error -> {

                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(activity_book_hotel.this.getApplicationContext(), "Please your network connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }) {



                /**
                 * Passing user parameters to our server
                 * @return
                 */
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("city_id", "city_id");
                    params.put("first_date", "check_in");
                    params.put("last_date", "check_out");
                    params.put("room_val", "room_val");
                    params.put("adult_count", "adult_count");
                    params.put("child_count", "child_count");
                    params.put("child_age1", "child_age1");
                    params.put("child_age2", "child_age2");
                    params.put("child_age", "child_age");
                    return params;
                }
            };

            int socketTimeout = 60000;
            RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            strReq.setRetryPolicy(policy);
            strReq.setTag(this);
            strReq.setShouldCache(false);

            MyApplication.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(this);


            MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);

        }

        }
```

I have to post these data to API as string and should receive response.

Comment: "I'm a beginner", how much experience do you have?

Comment: what type of errors you get ? you should give us little bit more to understand. then someone can help you. If you just post the code, no one can understand exactly what do you want here ! cheers :)